# Non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 mode regular expression

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pcre, character-class

### Question

Despite the PHP manual stating:

> [*"In UTF-8 mode, characters with values greater than 128 do not match any of the POSIX character classes."*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)

Why do Persian digits match `\d` or `[[:digit:]]` in "UTF-8 mode"?

### Elaboration

In an answerer's remark in a [non-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37655652/255756) it is mentioned that in regular expressions, `\d` does not only match ASCII digits `0` thru `9` but also, for example, Persian digits (`۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷`).

The above mentioned question is tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) but the behavior can be observed in PHP as well. With this in mind I wrote the following "test":

```
$string = 'I have ۳ apples and 5 oranges';
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $capture);
```

The resulting array `$capture` contains a match on `5` *only*.

Using the `u` modifier to turn on "UTF-8 mode" and running this:

```
$string = 'I have ۳ apples and 5 oranges';
preg_match_all('/\d+/u', $string, $capture);
```

results in `$capture` containing matches on both `۳` and `5`.

### Notes

- this question refers to PHP 5.6.22 (newest to date)
- both tests were executed while explicitly using the `C` locale.

Comment: The first test without `u` flag is non-sense when your string is not in ASCII, since the match will be carried out with byte semantic. If you use `\w` with [SHIFT-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS#Shift_JIS_byte_map) encoded string, you may match the second byte of some a character. See example section in this answer for explanation about non-UTF mode and consequences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954580/maximum-hex-value-in-regex/30556342#30556342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the documentation is broken. And it's not the only place where it is so, unfortunately.

PHP uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) under the hood to implement its `preg_*` functions. PCRE's documentation is thus authoritative there. PHP's documentation is based on PCRE's, but it looks like you found yet another mistake.

Here's what you can read in [PCRE's docs](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC10) (emphasis mine):

> **By default, characters with values greater than 128 do not match any of the POSIX character classes.** However, if the `PCRE_UCP` option is passed to `pcre_compile()`, some of the classes are changed so that Unicode character properties are used. This is achieved by replacing certain POSIX classes by other sequences, as follows:
>
> ```
> [:alnum:]  becomes  \p{Xan}
> [:alpha:]  becomes  \p{L}
> [:blank:]  becomes  \h
> [:digit:]  becomes  \p{Nd}
> [:lower:]  becomes  \p{Ll}
> [:space:]  becomes  \p{Xps}
> [:upper:]  becomes  \p{Lu}
> [:word:]   becomes  \p{Xwd}
> ```

If you dig further in PHP's docs, you'll find [the following](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> ### u (`PCRE_UTF8`)
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and the subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause the `preg_*` function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level `E_WARNING`. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

This is, unfortunately, a lie. The `u` modifier in PHP means `PCRE_UTF8 | PCRE_UCP` (UCP stands for Unicode Character Properties). The `PCRE_UCP` flag is the one that changes the meaning of `\d`, `\w` and the like, as you can see from the docs above. Your tests confirm that.

---

As a side note, don't infer properties of one regex flavor from another. It doesn't always work (heh, even [this chart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) forgot about the `PCRE_UCP` option).

Comment: Thanks for that elaborate answer, Lucas. Using this information, I've filed a [documentation bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72353). Let's see if it gets squashed or, indeed, corrected.